# DVD/BluRay combi drive not mounted / setup properly

Tags: mount, drive, blu-ray, optical

I have Laptop with a BluRay/DVD combi drive which means this drive has a BluRay and a DVD laser.

I followed the [ArchWiki > BluRay > PlayBack](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Blu-ray#Playback) guide to mount a BluRay disk (actual BluRay movie):

```bash
$ apt-get install libbluray-bin
$ apt-get install libaacs0
# Copied KEYDB.cfg into ~/.config/aacs
$ mkdir /media/bluray
$ mount /dev/sr0 /media/bluray
mount: /media/bluray: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

Unfortunately it says `no medium` is found and i think this is because the optical drive is not setup properly.

The gnome disk utility tool lists two optical drives:

[image: CD Drive]

[image: CD/DVD Drive]

As you can see, the Disks tool lists a CD Drive Model `HL-DT-ST BD-RE BT30N (GV01)`, but this "disk" is not listed as a device.

The other CD/DVD entry does not specify any drive info but lists the optical drive as device `/dev/sr0`.

As i was searching for an answer i have used to several commands to get info about the status of the optical drive:

```bash
$ lshw -C disk
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: status=open

$ cd-drive
cd-drive
cd-drive version 2.1.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003-2005, 2007-2008, 2011-2015, 2017 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
The driver selected is GNU/Linux
The default device for this driver is /dev/cdrom

Drivers available...
  GNU/Linux ioctl and MMC driver     
  cdrdao (TOC) disk image driver     
  bin/cuesheet disk image driver     
  Nero NRG disk image driver         

CD-ROM drive supports some nonstandard or degenerate set of MMC

                       Drive: /dev/cdrom
Vendor                      : 
Model                       : 
Revision                    : 
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : No
Can close tray                            : No
Can disable manual eject                  : No
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : No
Can hard reset device                     : No

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : No
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : No
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : No
  Can read C2 Errors                      : No
  Can read IRSC                           : No
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : No
  Can play audio                          : No
  Can read CD-DA                          : No
  Can read CD-R                           : No
  Can read CD-RW                          : No
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : No

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : No
  Can write DVD-R                         : No
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : No
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
```

Most interest is that `lshw` (`lshw -C disk`) does NOT list ANY hardware with the model and serial number info that gnome disk utility knows.

1. **Where does the gnome disk utility tool gets info about the listed "disks"?**
2. **How do i properly setup the drive so that i can mount a BluRay?**

If you need any further command outputs you can comment them and i will provide output in the question!

Comment: Do you actually have a BluRay disk inserted?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes